# Why is node.js not running external js files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows-terminal

I started the node.js part of my Web Development course, the introductory video shows the teacher creating new js and html files using the terminal, then runs the js file with node, I followed the steps and the js script ran, then on the next video, the teacher makes another js script with a console.log("Some hello message") and a second console.log(process.argv) I type this in VSCode, I try running it as I was taught: node fileName.js and the script doesn't runs, so I thought there was a typo or something was wrong with my script but it was not, and typing node filenName.js doesn't runs any script no matter the location, name or content of the script, I spent almost all day on this with no results, I just keep getting the same message **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Identifier**, and I get the same result if I type the specific location of the file instead of being in the folder with the js script, like this: node c/Users/user/Documents/fileName.js

I'm in the folder with js file I want to run, and I've tried placing the script in the root directory that my command line starts in and I've tried running scripts from other directories that are not the default, the result is the same message.

If I type .load fileName.js the script runs, it seems to be a specific problem with running the script with node fileName.js and I'm completely lost, I looked for answers here but I didn't found a solution for my specific problem, so I didn't felt like implementing any of the solutions for kind of similar problems since they involved changing default directories, and other measures that others said they didn't recommended because they could mess with administrator functions and honestly this is my first day using node, I'm not quite sure how to proceed here or if it's a small problem with an easy fix or if I have to remove and reinstall node which I read can be kind of a pain too since you have to scrub the system manually to get a fresh node install.[My node.js not running a simple js script][1]

Command line

```
ramaz@DESKTOP-28ABSA2 MINGW64 ~/Documents
$ node
Welcome to Node.js v14.16.0.
Type ".help" for more information.
> node firstScript.js
node firstScript.js
     ^^^^^^^^^^^

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
>
```

JavaScript file

```
for (let i = 0; i <  10; i++) {
    console.log("Hello From First Script!")
}
```

Conclusion: this was a non-issue, the teacher of my course just runs node fileName.js in the command line, he never goes in REPL, and I want to thank you guys for taking your time to reply to this.

Comment: You will have to show the actual script and command line you're trying to run.  This message `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Identifier` means you have a script error.  We need to see what line that occurs on and see the exact error message.

Comment: Questions about code here MUST include the actual code you're asking about.  Code should be pasted into your question as TEXT, not in images.  There are a whole host of good reasons for that.  It should be trivial for you to paste your actual script into your question and format it appropriately as code.  If you want help here, that is required.

Comment: Please use the "edit" link below your question to put the code into your question.  Multi-line code is not readable in comments.

Comment: To run a script from the command line, type this directly into the OS command prompt without first going into the repl: `node firstScript.js`.  Don't first type `node` as that starts the repl.

Comment: Yup, that's how the teacher did it, I don't know where I got the idea of being in repl before I ran the script, sorry for wasting your time, I'm new to programming, good night.

Comment: Everyone has to start somewhere.  Glad you got it figured out.

Comment: Thank you, tried it when you told me to, and went to the video again and the teachers types .exit before running the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went ahead and created the same firstScript.js file and its contents in my Documents directory. I don't think re-installing node is necessary. I think the issue is simply a limitation with the node repl.

The moment you enter node into your terminal, you're entering Node REPL.it mode - a very good playground for testing JS code. [Here's more info on this:](https://nodejs.dev/learn/how-to-use-the-nodejs-repl)

Unfortunately, on repl.it you cannot run any file except the original file. If you want to run another file on node.js, you can do this:

[image: Entering commands into terminal]

What I'm doing here is simply importing the file firstScript.js into my node REPL and executing it all in one line. Let me know if there are any more questions!

Comment: It runs!i it runs! Thank you!, I saw require in another post but thought it was for more complicated things, and since the teacher in my course just ran the scripts with the same syntax I thought my node was broken, another issue might be that he codes on IOS, or might not be, but thank you!

Comment: I chose your answer but my rep is too low, thank you for your time and have a good night!

Comment: REPL.it is a website. REPL means Read-Execute-Print-Loop.

Answer (score 0):

I just followed your instructions exactly.
I created a file named '''myfile.js''' that has in it

```
console.log("some hello message")
console.log(process.argv)

for (let i = 0; i <  10; i++) {
    console.log("Hello From First Script!")
}
```

then, in the directory that has the file I type node myfile.js and it works fine.

it prints out

```
some hello message
[
  'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
  'C:\\Users\\WilliamOHara\\subscripify-repositories\\myfile.js'
]
Hello From First Script!
Hello From First Script!
Hello From First Script!
Hello From First Script!
Hello From First Script!
Hello From First Script!
Hello From First Script!
Hello From First Script!
Hello From First Script!
Hello From First Script!
```

Getting started developing can be a little frustrating. Make sure that the contents of your file is exactly

```
console.log("some hello message")
console.log(process.argv)
for (let i = 0; i <  10; i++) {
    console.log("Hello From First Script!")
}
```

you may have forgotten the parentheses around `process.argv` or left out the `.` between `console` and `log`

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure If I conveyed in my post that it seems to be a very specific problem with my node.js, the instructions from my course where very clear and simple, my console.log(process.argv) is enclosed in paranthesis, in multiple js files that I created in different directories to try and run any of them,  in subsequent js files I deleted console.log(process.argv) and left only console.log("simple string ") because I thought that somehow process.argv was causing the problem but the scripts don't run

Comment: I see - its hard to for me to think that it would be a problem with your node - if it is returning "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" that means its running. Although - uninstalling it from windows and reinstalling it wouldn't hurt. if you do Id follow the instructions on the node.js website rather than the course material for that one... good luck!

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't running it correctly, no need to uninstall or anything ,thankfully, I just have to pay more attention in the lectures before freaking out, just typing node fileName.js without starting REPL in node, I was doing that every time and the external scripts can only run in REPL with reprise like Timeo Williams showed me.